# How can I check if a player stands on a tile and that tile has a specific materia change it to another material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to have a player stand on a platform and if that platform has material 1 on it change it to 2 and if it has material 2 change it to material 3.

```
public class TileHealth : MonoBehaviour
{

public Material Stage0;
public Material Stage1;
public Material Stage2;
public Material Stage3;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.name.Equals("Player"))
    {
        Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        if (render.material == Stage0) {

            render.material = Stage1;

        } else if (render.material == Stage1) {

            render.material = Stage2;

        } else if (render.material == Stage2) {

            render.material = Stage3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What, like [Q*bert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert)?

Comment: yes similar to Qbert

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is not working, since renderer.material might assign a copy of your material, thus the equality check fails. Good news is you don't need the check. Just use an array, which also allows for a more flexible setup:

```
public class TileHealth : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private Material[] materials;
    private int materialIndex;
    private int materialCount;
    private Renderer renderer;

    void Awake(){
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        materialCount = materials.Length;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            materialIndex++;
            if(materialIndex < materialCount){
                renderer.material = materials[materialIndex];
            } else {
                Debug.Log("no more materials available");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I also changed the collider check to use Unity's [tag system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html), since this is faster and more reliable than checking names.